# How to get all information with duplicates from MongoDB search

Tags: java, mongodb, collections, aggregation

I have MongoDB collections and I am trying to find all numberId fields using aggregation, but in the response I get all fields without duplicates

```
Aggregation agg = TypedAggregation.newAggregation(
                TypedAggregation.match(Criteria.where("numBerId").regex("^" + numBerId, "i")
                        .andOperator(Criteria.where("numBerId").ne(""))),
                TypedAggregation.group("numBerId"),
                TypedAggregation.limit(20000),
                TypedAggregation.sort(Direction.ASC, "_id"));

        Document rawResults = mongo.aggregate(agg, collectionName(), Document.class).getRawResults();
        return rawResults.getList("results", Document.class)
                .stream()
                .map(d -> (String) d.get("_id"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

How to get all fields with duplicates, thanks in advance

Comment: Just remove the group() stage

Comment: i get error "org.bson.types.ObjectId cannot be cast to java.lang.String"

Comment: but i dont understand why i am getting error when i removed group stage

Answer (score 0):

You could simply remove the `group` stage from your aggregation pipeline

Comment: i get error "org.bson.types.ObjectId cannot be cast to java.lang.String"

Comment: Maybe your return statement has to be modified `return rawResults.getList("results", Document.class); that's why u get an error for casting into string

Comment: but i dont understand why i am getting error when i removed group stage